# Jquery two different class using multiple input text subtraction

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating html page multi input value record display using jquery subtract two class value. please help me

**html**

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="quarter_no[]" value="<?=$value->quarter_no?>">Quarter <?=$value->quarter_no?></td>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="receipt_no[]" value="<?=$value->receipt_no?>" placeholder="Quarter1 Recept No."></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control credited" id="quarter1_amtPaid" name="amount_credited[]" value="<?=$value->amount_credited?>" placeholder="0.00"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control deducted" id="quarter1_taxDeducted" name="amount_tax_deduction[]" value="<?=$value->amount_tax_deducted?>" placeholder="0.00"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control remitted" id="quarter1_taxRemitted" name="amount_tax_remitted[]" value="<?=$value->amount_tax_remitted?>" placeholder="0.00"></td>
```

**jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").on("blur", ".credited, .deducted", function(){
       var arr = document.getElementsByName('amount_credited[]');
         var tot=0;
         for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
                 tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
         }
         document.getElementById('quarter1_taxRemitted').value = tot;

     });
   })
```

Comment: So, what is your question exactly? Do we have to guess what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".credited , .deducted").on("blur", function () {
            console.log($('#quarter1_amtPaid').val());
            var paid = $('#quarter1_amtPaid').val();
            var Deducted = $('#quarter1_taxDeducted').val();
            var tot = parseFloat(paid) - parseFloat(Deducted);
            $('#quarter1_taxDeducted').val(tot);

        });
    })
</script>
```

try this one.